# How can I plot 10 normal distribution in one graph ( example picture included)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, normal-distribution

Assume I have 10 normal distribution how can I plot them like picture below.

my normal distribution samples:

```
import numpy as np

q = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)
random_distr = []
for i in q:
    random_distr.append(np.random.normal(i, 1, 1000))
```

the plot I want to create:
[image]

Comment: Is this violin plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`pyplot.violinplot()` function](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.violinplot.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

q = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)
random_distr = []
for i in q:
    random_distr.append(np.random.normal(i, 1, 1000))
    
plt.violinplot(random_distr)
plt.show()
```

[image]

You may also want to check [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html).